# [chef]: View all available data bags on a node

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, databags

In our organization, the devs are being given ownership to own the cookbooks. The cookbooks were initially written by the ops guys. I am a java guy and not a chef/ruby/ops expert. I have been given a task to debug an issue where the cookbook is not reading from the right data-bag.

Is it possible to to list all available data bags on a chef node? I tried something like this but it's taking a long time.

```
# find / -type f  -not -name "*test*" -exec grep -IHnl data_bag {} \; | grep -v gems
```

The code I am looking at is:

```
secret2 = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret(secret)
passwords = data_bag_item(id, item, secret2)
```

When chef-client runs on a node, does it combine all data_bag json files into 1 data structure. While writing the cookbook, do I have to specify which data_bag to load?

Update:

This command ran very quickly after I limited my search to just chef's directories:

```
# find /run/chef /opt/chef /var/chef /etc/chef  -type f  -not -name "*test*" -exec grep -IHnl data_bag {} \; | grep -v gems

/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/users/resources/manage.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/users/CHANGELOG.md
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/users/metadata.json
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/users/README.md
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_users/recipes/default.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_users/attributes/default.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_users/README.md
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_users/.kitchen.yml
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_base/.kitchen.yml
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/splunk/recipes/mysqlmonitor.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/splunk/attributes/default.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/splunk/.kitchen.yml
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_service/recipes/config.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_service/attributes/default.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_service/.kitchen.yml
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_service/README.md
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_service2/attributes/default.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_service2/recipes/certificates.rb
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_service2/README.md
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_service2/metadata.json
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_nginx/.kitchen.yml
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

as you can see in [data bags chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags/#load-with-recipe-dsl) and also you specified that you are looking for the code

```
secret2 = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret(secret)
passwords = data_bag_item(id, item, secret2)
```

so for your question

> While writing the cookbook, do I have to specify which data_bag to load?

the answer is yes. refer to the second line in your snippet, which specifies to load a data bag item named `item` from a data bag named `id` and decrept it using `secret2` key.

now to your second question:

> When chef-client runs on a node, does it combine all data_bag json files into 1 data structure.

from what i know, the answer is no. chef-client fetches a specific data bag from the chef-server on-demand (per what is written in the cookbook).